# read/output multiple lines from a file in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following file:

```
FRN  3 [Link Technology Indicator] = 24 : bNonADSB=0,bUAT=1, b1090ES=0, iLinkVersion=2, bUnknownLinkVersion=0
FRN  4 [Time of Applicability] = 63D63F00 : Seconds = 51116,  Frac = 63,  51116.492,  14:11:56.492, TOAVel = 0, 0.0 seconds
FRN  5 [Target Address] = 01AAAAAA : Address = aaaaaa,11184810  Qualifier=1,  Dup=0
FRN  6 [Integrity and Accuracy Parameters] = 108020 : UTC=0, NIC=2, SILSup=0, SIL=0, NACp=0, TestMode=0, Validation=0, NACv=0, NICBaro=0
FRN  7 [Latitude/Longitude] = 1BB8CAC8F823 : Lat = 38.98382664,  lon=-77.38694429
FRN  8 [Pressure Altitude] = 8258 : PressureAlt=15000, PressureRes=2
FRN  9 [Velocity (Airborne)] = 03DD1EE821 : VVSource=0, SuperSonic=False
```

I would like to 'grep' for multiple lines using python:

example: grep for line starting FRN 3 and FRN 8.

I am able to grep for 1 line but having difficulties grepping for multiple lines

```
# Open the data file
file_path = "mopsV22.txt"
pattern = 'FRN 3'

def grep_a(file_path, pattern, after_lines=2):
  with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

    match_lines = []

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
      if re.search(pattern, line):
        match_lines.extend(lines[i:i+1+after_lines])

return match_lines

matched_lines = grep_a(file_path, pattern, after_lines=0)
for line in matched_lines:
  print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Did you try `pattern = 'FRN [38]'`?

Comment: what about if I want to search for something that is greater than 9, FRN  10 or FRN 18 along with something less than FRN 10

Comment: If you want to match number ranges, I don't think regex patterns are what you want. Otherwise, greater than 9 would look like `FRN 1\d+`. Regular grep command works the same way; so there's no advantage of using the Python for that. The alternative solution would be to parse the number, then do a proper numeric comparison

Comment: Well, for one thing, the file has `FRN<space><space>3`, but your code has `FRN<space>3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
pattern='FRN ( 3| 8|10|18)'
```